# when another tab is selected ;preveously selected tab style is remaining activated

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I am using simple tab ;created using css.

I have current class to show currently active tab . i am managing using jquery

```
$(".Tabs").click(function(){

$(this).addClass('current ');

});
```

This works fine but it does not remove class from previously activated tab . Please help

Comment: Please share complete code. It will help identify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
$(".Tabs").click(function(){

$(this).addClass('current');

$(".Tabs").not($(this)).removeClass('current');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not removing the current class from the previous active tab.

You can do this by removing the `current` class from the previous like follows:

```
$(".Tabs").click(function(){

$(this).parent().find('current ').removeClass('current');

$(this).addClass('current ');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the class from siblings:

```
$(".Tabs").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("current").addClass('current');
});
```